# SQL Object no longer exists while inserting data

Tags: sql, oracle

While I try to insert some data into my table I get an error: `ORACLE execute error: ORA-08103: object no longer exists`
Query:

```
INSERT
INTO MA_USER.RESPONCES_NEW_2016_10_17_22_10
  (
    GCC_CONTACT_ID,
    GCC_PARENT_CONTACT_ID,
    GCC_SESSION_ID,
    GCC_REQUEST_ID,
    GCC_REGISTRY_ID,
    CONTACT_ID,
    CREATE_DTTM,
    GCC_RESULT_CD,
    CONTACT_DTTM,
    "TYPE",
    GCC_RESULT_TERMINAL_FLG,
    CUSTOMER_GCC_ID,
    SMARTSCRIPT_CD ,
    COMMUNICATION_TYPE,
    "FIRST_NM" ,
    "LAST_NM" ,
    "MIDDLE_NM" ,
    "GENDER_CD" ,
    "BIRTH_DT" ,
    "IIN_NUM" ,
    "MOBILE_PHONE_NUM" ,
    "HOME_PHONE_NUM" ,
    "REGION_NM" ,
    "CITY_NM" ,
    "COMMENT" ,
    "QUEUE_ADDED_DTTM" ,
    "OPERATOR_NM" ,
    "QUEUE_EXTRACT_DTTM" ,
    "REQUEST_START_DTTM" ,
    "REQUEST_END_DTTM" ,
    "CALL_DURATION_TOTAL" ,
    "INFO_SOURCE_DESC" ,
    "APPOINTMENT_FLG" ,
    "APPOINTMENT_DTTM" ,
    "REMINDER_DTTM" ,
    "APPOINTMENT_PLACE_DESC" ,
    "SOLD_PRODUCT_NM" ,
    "LANGUAGE_CD" ,
    "TOPIC" ,
    "REQUESTED_PRODUCT_NM" ,
    "VISIT_REASON_NM"
  )
SELECT GCC_CONTACT_ID          AS GCC_CONTACT_ID,
  MAX(GCC_PARENT_CONTACT_ID)   AS GCC_PARENT_CONTACT_ID,
  MAX(GCC_SESSION_ID)          AS GCC_SESSION_ID ,
  MAX(GCC_REQUEST_ID)          AS GCC_REQUEST_ID,
  MAX(GCC_REGISTRY_ID)         AS GCC_REGISTRY_ID,
  MAX(CONTACT_ID_test)         AS CONTACT_ID,
  sysdate                      AS CREATE_DTTM,
  MAX(GCC_RESULT_CD)           AS GCC_RESULT_CD,
  MAX(CONTACT_DTTM)            AS CONTACT_DTTM,
  MAX("TYPE")                  AS TYPE,
  MAX(GCC_RESULT_TERMINAL_FLG) AS GCC_RESULT_TERMINAL_FLG ,
  MAX(CUSTOMER_GCC_ID)         AS CUSTOMER_GCC_ID,
  MAX(SMARTSCRIPT_CD)          AS SMARTSCRIPT_CD ,
  MAX(COMMUNICATION_TYPE)      AS COMMUNICATION_TYPE ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('FIRST_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "FIRST_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('LAST_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "LAST_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('MIDDLE_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "MIDDLE_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('GENDER_CD')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "GENDER_CD" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('BIRTH_DT')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "BIRTH_DT" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('IIN_NUM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "IIN_NUM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('MOBILE_PHONE_NUM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "MOBILE_PHONE_NUM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('HOME_PHONE_NUM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "HOME_PHONE_NUM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('REGION_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "REGION_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('CITY_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "CITY_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('COMMENT')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "COMMENT" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('QUEUE_ADDED_DTTM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "QUEUE_ADDED_DTTM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('OPERATOR_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "OPERATOR_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('QUEUE_EXTRACT_DTTM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "QUEUE_EXTRACT_DTTM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('REQUEST_START_DTTM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "REQUEST_START_DTTM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('REQUEST_END_DTTM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "REQUEST_END_DTTM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('CALL_DURATION_TOTAL')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "CALL_DURATION_TOTAL" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('INFO_SOURCE_DESC')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "INFO_SOURCE_DESC" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('APPOINTMENT_FLG')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "APPOINTMENT_FLG" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('APPOINTMENT_DTTM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "APPOINTMENT_DTTM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('REMINDER_DTTM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "REMINDER_DTTM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('APPOINTMENT_PLACE_DESC')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "APPOINTMENT_PLACE_DESC" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('SOLD_PRODUCT_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "SOLD_PRODUCT_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('LANGUAGE_CD')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "LANGUAGE_CD" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('TOPIC')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "TOPIC" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('REQUESTED_PRODUCT_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "REQUESTED_PRODUCT_NM" ,
  MAX(
  CASE
    WHEN UPPER(param_nm) = UPPER('VISIT_REASON_NM')
    THEN PARAM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS "VISIT_REASON_NM"
FROM
  (SELECT h.*,
    hp.*,
    con.contact_id AS contact_id_test,
    dict.GCC_RESULT_TERMINAL_FLG
  FROM INTEGRATION_PROD.GCC_HISTORY h
  LEFT JOIN INTEGRATION_PROD.GCC_HISTORY_PARAMS HP
  ON H.INT_GCC_ID = HP.INT_GCC_ID
  LEFT JOIN CDM.MA_CONTACT con
  ON h.GCC_SESSION_ID = con.GCC_SESSION_ID
  LEFT JOIN INTEGRATION_PROD.DICT_GCC_RESULT dict
  ON h.GCC_RESULT_CD         = dict.GCC_RESULT_CD
  WHERE TYPE                != 'SAS'
  AND GCC_PARENT_CONTACT_ID IS NULL
  AND h.GCC_request_id      IS NULL
  AND con.CONTACT_ID        IS NULL
  AND h.INT_STATUS           = 'NEW'
  ) rs_new
WHERE rs_new.gcc_session_id IS NULL
OR ( rs_new.gcc_session_id  IS NOT NULL
AND rs_new.CONTACT_DTTM      =
  (SELECT MIN(rs_min_date.CONTACT_DTTM)
  FROM
    (SELECT h.CONTACT_DTTM,
      h.GCC_SESSION_ID
    FROM INTEGRATION_PROD.GCC_HISTORY h
    LEFT JOIN INTEGRATION_PROD.GCC_HISTORY_PARAMS HP
    ON H.INT_GCC_ID = HP.INT_GCC_ID
    LEFT JOIN CDM.MA_CONTACT con
    ON h.GCC_SESSION_ID = con.GCC_SESSION_ID
    LEFT JOIN INTEGRATION_PROD.DICT_GCC_RESULT dict
    ON h.GCC_RESULT_CD         = dict.GCC_RESULT_CD
    WHERE TYPE                != 'SAS'
    AND GCC_PARENT_CONTACT_ID IS NULL
    AND h.GCC_request_id      IS NULL
    AND con.CONTACT_ID        IS NULL
    AND h.INT_STATUS           = 'NEW'
    ) rs_min_date
  WHERE rs_new.GCC_SESSION_ID = rs_min_date.GCC_SESSION_ID
  ))
GROUP BY gcc_contact_id;
```

I think that there arent any truncate or drop operation with tables in this query. This query takes about 30 minutes. Maybe "Object no longer exists" - its because of long running query?

Answer (score 1):

It looks some other user/session/application process is performing a TRUNCATE (or DROP or RECREATE) while the query is running in another session.

```
INTEGRATION_PROD.GCC_HISTORY h
JOIN CDM.MA_CONTACT con
JOIN INTEGRATION_PROD.DICT_GCC_RESULT dict
JOIN INTEGRATION_PROD.GCC_HISTORY_PARAMS HP
```

I suspect, it is most likely 'DICT_GCC_RESULT' based upon its name. Please check.

[See other possible causes here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_08103_object_no_longer_exists.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the internet:

ORA-08103 object no longer exists

Cause: The object has been deleted by another user since the operation began.  Or a prior incomplete recovery restored the database to a point in time during the deletion of the object.